# Is there a way to customize Flutter drawable elements by language?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a way to customize the elements for drawables in Flutter according to locale, screen size, or dimensions as usual on Android with Java?

For example, we use in Android studio with java to dedicated a drawable elements for Arabic, English or Turkish :

```
drawable-ar
drawable-tr
```

How can we customize like this in flutter ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way but not like Android with Java.

You have to do some `if else` statements.

For example:

```dart
// you have to use some kind of package to get localization working well, if you have custom way just get a provider to have the locale always inywhere so you can check it from anywhere in the app
if (locale == Locale("en")) {
    return EnglishWidget();
} else if (locale == Locale("ar")) {
    return ArabicWidget();
} else {
    return DefaultWidget();
}
```